# FHIR Resource for Treatment Parameters

Tags: hl7-fhir

What would be the best FHIR Resource to represent parameters for a device treatment (treatment duration, blood flow, volume of medication) ? These parameters are Patient dependant. I looked at "Care Plan" and "Procedure" resources, but they don't seem to represent such kind of data. Maybe it is possible using attributes "Timing", "Quantity" and "Details" of Care Plan/Activity relation ?

All answers are welcome.

Comment: Are these independent of a single order? (If order-specific, I'd say MedicationPrescription for most)

Comment: It's not specific to an order. It's a repetitive daily hemodialysis treatment and the parameters of the treatment could change some days. I was thinking of an "Care-Plan", linked to an hemodialysis "Activity". But the problem is that the Activity detail contains only a 0..1 relation to a "Simple" detail containing two measurables parameters : dailyAmount and quantity, whereas I need many parameters such as blood volume, hemodialysis duration, number of cycles, pressures. That's not only a medication quantity.. How could it be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Care Plans can have lots of discrete data associated with them, but most of it is relegated to extensions, as few systems support a lot of discrete information.  Care Plan sounds like the right solution for your requirement.